# Can't map fetched data using hooks

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, jsx

I try to show info about music stored in music hook and the browser complains showing me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Console shows me the data that was fetched. It's an array with 25 objects.
I tried both music.data && music.data.map

```
function App() {
  
  const [ playlist, setPlaylist ] = useState('beyonce')
  const [music, saveMusic ] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('new playlist')
    fetch(`https://rapidapi.p.rapidapi.com/search?q=${playlist}`, {
          "method": "GET",
          "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "deezerdevs-deezer.p.rapidapi.com",
            
          }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => saveMusic(json))
       
  
  }, [playlist])
  console.log(music)
  return (
    <div>
       <h2>useEffect practice</h2>
      <div>
       <button onClick={() => setPlaylist('beyonce')}>Playlist 1</button>
       <button onClick={() => setPlaylist('eminem')}>Playlist 2</button>
       <button onClick={() => setPlaylist('ac/dc')}>Playlist 3</button>
       </div>
       <div>
         <h5>{playlist}</h5>
        
         {music.data.map(i => {
           return (
             <>
                  <img style={{width: '100px'}} src={i.album.cover_big} />
                 <p>{i.title}</p>
             </>
           )
         })}
       </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I try to show info about music stored in music hook and the browser complains showing me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Comment: Your initial state is an empty array. Arrays don't have `.data` property. Did you mean `useState({ data: [] })`?

Comment: try with `music.data && music.data.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`music.data` does not exist on the first render. You can either initialize `music` with `{ data: [] }`:

```
const [music, saveMusic ] = useState({ data: [] })
```

Or check if `music.data` exists before trying to `map` it:

```
{music.data && music.data.map(i => {
  return (
    <>
        <img style={{width: '100px'}} src={i.album.cover_big} />
        <p>{i.title}</p>
    </>
  )
})}
```

If you want to make sure that `music.data` is an array, you can use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).